# audio not working with phoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Hi i try to add sound to my game i used aphoneGap code to do it :

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    // 
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    // 
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback 
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    // 
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" 

     onclick="playAudio('http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_- 
      _rockGuitar.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
     </body>
   </html>
```

it works fine , but when i change the source of sound it didn't work here's the code :

```
playAudio("file:///android_asset/www/sounds/introDino.mp3");
```

Any idea please,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your path to "/android_asset/www/sounds/introDino.mp3" and it will be fine. Read my mini tutorial for Android:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html

Comment: @simon-macdonald:  Couldn't a relative path work, such `"./sounds/introDino.mp3"` from `www/index.html` ?

Answer (score 2):

This function will play sound using the HTML5 Audio API if available, with fallback to the PhoneGap Media API if not:

```
function playAudio(src) {

    // HTML5 Audio
    if (typeof Audio != "undefined") { 
        new Audio(src).play() ;

    // Phonegap media
    } else if (typeof device != "undefined") {

        // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
        if (device.platform == 'Android') {
            src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
        }

        var mediaRes = new Media(src,
            function onSuccess() {
                // release the media resource once finished playing
                mediaRes.release();
            },
            function onError(e){
                console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
            });
        mediaRes.play();

    } else {
        console.log("no sound API to play: " + src);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for me using Android 4.2.2, The `typeof Audio != "undefined"` resolves to `true` and fails to play with `Failed to open file '/android_asset/www/ticktock.mp3'`, however even if the audio file path is correct it still fails.

Comment: @DavidHancock: did you found a fix and could you share back your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Due fact that Audio object on new Android versions (may be on other platforms) available and not 'undefined' both previous answers will not work. So I upgraded code to :

```
function playSound(src){
var devicePlatform = (typeof device !== 'undefined' && device.platform)? device.platform: null;
if (typeof Audio !== "undefined" && devicePlatform === null) {          // HTML5 Audio
    new Audio(src).play() ;
} else if ( devicePlatform ) {              // Phonegap media
if (devicePlatform === 'Android') {     // Android needs the search path explicitly specified
    src = '/android_asset/www/' + src;
}
var media  = new Media(src,
function onSuccess() {
    media.release();                // Release the media resource once finished playing
},
function onError(e){
    console.log("error playing sound: " + JSON.stringify(e));
}
);
media.play({numberOfLoops: 1});
} else {
    console.log("no sound API to play: " + src);
}
}
```

Also must say that before all you must add to cordova build 'device' and 'media' plugins otherwise nothing will work. Plugins available [here](http://plugreg.com/plugins)