# Using local file for Web Audio API in Javascript

Tags: html, client-side, web-audio-api

I'm trying to get sound working on my iPhone game using the Web Audio API. The problem is that this app is entirely client side. I want to store my mp3s in a local folder (and without being user input driven) so I can't use XMLHttpRequest to read the data. I was looking into using FileSystem but Safari doesn't support it.

Is there any alternative?

Edit: Thanks for the below responses. Unfortunately the Audio API is horribly slow for games. I had this working and the latency just makes the user experience unacceptable. To clarify, what I need is sounething like -

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'file:///./../sounds/beep-1.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    dogBarkingBuffer = buffer;
}, onError);
}
request.send();
```

But this gives me the errors -

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///sounds/beep-1.mp3. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

I understand the security risks with reading local files but surely within your own domain should be ok?

Comment: You may find answer to this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556437/audio-not-working-with-phonegap

Comment: Have you considered local storage?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the above. I'm storing the audio files in the same domain as my javascript. Just don't know how I go about accessing it or if it's even allowed?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem and I found this very simple solution.

```js
audio_file.onchange = function(){
  var files = this.files;
  var file = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]); 
              audio_player.src = file; 
  audio_player.play();
};
```

```html
<input id="audio_file" type="file" accept="audio/*" />
<audio id="audio_player" />
```

You can test here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Tv8Cm/

Comment: Incredible. So simple!

Comment: Note: While this works, it will have a remarkable lag, at least on slower devices, making this likely unsuitable for gaming sounds, as the OP mentioned.

Answer (score 17):

Ok, it's taken me two days of prototyping different solutions and I've finally figured out how I can do this without storing my resources on a server. There's a few blogs that detail this but I couldn't find the full solution in one place so I'm adding it here. This may be considered a bit hacky by seasoned programmers but it's the only way I can see this working, so if anyone has a more elegent solution I'd love to hear it.

The solution was to store my sound files as a Base64 encoded string. The sound files are relatively small (less than 30kb) so I'm hoping performance won't be too much of an issue. Note that I put 'xxx' in front of some of the hyperlinks as my n00b status means I can't post more than two links.

**Step 1: create Base 64 sound font**

First I need to convert my mp3 to a Base64 encoded string and store it as JSON. I found a website that does this conversion for me here - xxxhttp://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php
You may need to remove return characters using a text editor but for anyone that needs an example I found some piano tones here - xxxhttps://raw.github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js/master/soundfont/acoustic_grand_piano-mp3.js
Note that in order to work with my example you're need to remove the header part *data:audio/mpeg;base64,*

**Step 2: decode sound font to ArrayBuffer**

You could implement this yourself but I found an API that does this perfectly (why re-invent the wheel, right?) - https://github.com/danguer/blog-examples/blob/master/js/base64-binary.js
Resource taken from - [here](http://blog.danguer.com/2011/10/24/base64-binary-decoding-in-javascript/)

**Step 3: Adding the rest of the code**

Fairly straightforward

```
var cNote  = acoustic_grand_piano.C2;
var byteArray = Base64Binary.decodeArrayBuffer(cNote); 
var context = new webkitAudioContext();

context.decodeAudioData(byteArray, function(buffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource(); // creates a sound source
    source.buffer = buffer;    
    source.connect(context.destination); // connect the source to the context's destination (the speakers)
    source.noteOn(0); 
}, function(err) { console.log("err(decodeAudioData): "+err); });
```

And that's it! I have this working through my desktop version of Chrome and also running on mobile Safari (iOS 6 only of course as Web Audio is not supported in older versions). It takes a couple of seconds to load on mobile Safari (Vs less than 1 second on desktop Chrome) but this might be due to the fact that it spends time downloading the sound fonts. It might also be the fact that iOS prevents any sound playing until a user interaction event has occured. I need to do more work looking at how it performs.

Hope this saves someone else the grief I went through.

Comment: very interesting! thanks for the details.  
Would this approach work on an audio file that it's being recorded by another concurrent process? out of the JS browser/engine

Answer (score 1):

Because ios apps are sandboxed, the web view (basically safari wrapped in phonegap) allows you to store your mp3 file locally. I.e, there is no "cross domain" security issue.

This is as of ios6 as previous ios versions didn't support web audio api

Answer (score -2):

Use [HTML5 Audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) for playing audio file in browser.

Ajax request works with http protocol so when you try to get audio file using file://, browser mark this request as cross domain request. Set following code in request header -

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Just added some details to the post (and why I can't use Audio)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding above gives me the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://beep-1.mp3/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Any other thoughts on this? This works fine when running it over WAMP but I want this completely offline (will probably be using PhoneGap but I can't work with it right now as I'm on Windows). I'm almost considering hacking this step by converting the files to something like Base64 encoded string and storing them but I'm not sure this will even work? Sorry, complete noob with this audio stuff.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header. Adding it to the request won't have any effect. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS to understand how it works.