# HTML5 play local audio file (c:\classical\chopin.wav) in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, html5-audio

How to play local audio file (c:\classical\chopin.wav - no file selection) in Google Chrome using HTML5 coding?

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074833/using-local-file-for-web-audio-api-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I'm not on a Windows machine right now. But you should try

```
<audio src="file:///C:/classical/chopin.wav" controls ></audio>
```

Of course, this only works, if the webpage is viewed locally on your machine.

Comment: Hi, no luck, player appear but speaker disabled. Thanks for the suggestion even without windows machine. Once you are in front of windows, can you try? The criteria are: Google Chrome + Local audio file (must be .wav) + HTML5 Coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Keep your audio file in html folder and this code will work.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="chopin.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Hi, all my wav files are stored in another file server, there are easily a few thousand of them (these are small wav file for voice recording for telesales). I am using azure website, and I can't store the file in the cloud as well. To the users, the audio (wav) files are at the local network drive F.