# I'm looking for a Cordova-plugin-media working example(demo)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm having trouble adding sound to my cordova app. I can't find an example on the npm/github documentation of cordova-plugin-media:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media
I've also tried to implement these two:
[Play sound on Phonegap app for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515699/play-sound-on-phonegap-app-for-android)
[audio not working with phoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556437/audio-not-working-with-phonegap)

No luck so far. Where can I find an up-to-date copy and paste example that works? Big thanks!

(Cordova version 5.1.1, I install the plugin through `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media`)

Comment: The examples from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media are working, I used them a few days ago.

Comment: I can't find a full example, an index.html with everything in it. There are just JS examples that don't work on their own, they need to be a part of something bigger.

Comment: You have du add the code examples to your cordova javascript file. If you don't know how to write a cordova app, then please  a have look at the demo cordova app, which you get after the install of cordova and read the documentation from cordova.

Comment: I know how to write a cordova app. What exactly do I need to app? I keep running in circles, I have no idea if I'm copying the right stuff and where the problem may lie. I'm currently trying to test it out through genymotion.

Comment: Please show your app code.

Comment: I just have a standard cordova create to which I try to add sound...
https://jsbin.com/dadinagaro/edit?html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index.js file should look like this, and remove your self written javascript in your index.html:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        var myMedia = new Media("http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/3926.mp3")
        myMedia.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false })

    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Comment: Finally something I can work on, thanks a lot. Though not even half of the code is in the examples on github.

Comment: why its only woking from an online link i cant ;play local files

Comment: @OussakiI would check permissions, you probably need to request permission to access local files.